# Reaction entropy in internal combustion engines

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, heat-engine

In air-standard analysis of internal combustion engines, the combustion phase is modeled as a heat input providing an energy corresponding to the reaction enthalpy. The entropy variation is calculated accordingly, and corresponds simply to the entropy increase induced by the heating up of the compressed gases (see for instance step 2-3 of the Otto cycle on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_cycle)).

However, the combustion reaction is also associated with a reaction entropy. It seems to me that this contribution should also be taken into account, so that the total entropy change is the sum of the entropy for heating up the reaction's products (as before) *plus* the reaction entropy.
This entropy change is entirely created entropy, since the system is isolated from the exterior during this step.

If this is correct, then the efficiency is reduced as compared to the air standard calculation: if more entropy has to be removed from the system to close the cycle, then more heat has to be expelled to the cold source, and less energy remains to provide work.

To clarify a bit more
[image: combustion]
it appears to me that the entropy change should be $dS=-dH_{comb}/T_i + dS_{comb}$, while usual analysis only account for the first term. It can be verified that $dS>0$ because, since the reaction is spontaneous, $dG_{comb}=dH_{comb}-TdS_{comb}<0$.

Does this reasoning make sense, or am I missing something ?

--- edit: added the figure

Comment: Please state your understanding of the definition of the Standard Entropy Change for a combustion reaction.

Comment: @ChetMiller I added a figure to clarify my point. I understand the combustion entropy as the difference between the entropy of products and that of reactants at the same temperature and (in this case) volume.

Comment: So you have the reaction taking. place at constant volume and, presumably, adiabatically, correct?  And you want to know the change in entropy for this change, correct?

Comment: @ChetMiller Not exactly. I know how to do this from basic thermochemistry. I also know how to estimate the efficiency of the Otto cycle in the usual textbook way. I try to understand how to connect the dots, since the heat input in the Otto cycle is supposed to originate from fuel combustion.

Comment: The standard change in internal energy is negative, so in order for the internal energy change in the engine combustion to be zero, the temperature of the products must rise.